# CS1061 C# 'object' does not contain a definition for "Split" and "Trim"

Tags: split, trim

How to fix it?

```
{
    var extensions = new HashSet<string>();

    foreach (
        var ext in
            Resources.Extensions.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine, " " },
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList())
        {
            extensions.Add(ext.Trim());
        }

        extensions.Remove(EncryptionFileExtension);

        return extensions;
}
```

error CS1061:

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Split' and no extension method 'Split' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

error CS1061:

```
'TSource' does not contain a definition for 'Trim' and no extension method 'Trim' accepting a first argument of type 'TSource' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: ext.ToString().Trim() ?

Comment: Thanks, but how to fix split?

Comment: Sorry, but do not know what Resources.Extensions is. Maybe there is already built in something like: SplitList ?

Comment: Yet error, i do not know how it fix

Comment: Implement Split in Resources.Extensions.

Comment: `Resources.Extensions` has type `object` so does not have a `Split` method. If you expect it to be a string at runtime you need to cast: `((string)Resources.Extensions).Split(...)`.